# Why isn't Kotlin complaining about ambiguity? And why is it calling the secondary constructor?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, ambiguity

I was testing something in Kotlin and now I won't be able to sleep properly if I don't find an answer.

Look at this class:

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int? = 0
) {
    constructor(
        secondName: String,
        secondAge: Int = 5
    ) : this(
        name = "$secondName 2",
        age = secondAge
    )
}

fun main() {
    val firstCase  = Person("Lorem")     // Complaints about ambiguity.
    val secondCase = Person("Lorem", 42) // Calls secondary constructor.
}
```

Complaining about ambiguity in the firstCase is understandable, but why it is not happening the same in the secondCase? And why did it decide to call the secondary constructor and not the main constructor?

Now if I add another parameter on the main constructor **with a default value**:

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int? = 0,
    val isAdult: Boolean = false
) {
    constructor(
        secondName: String,
        secondAge: Int = 5
    ) : this(
        name = "$secondName 2",
        age = secondAge
    )
}

fun main() {
    val thirdCase = Person("Lorem") // Calls secondary constructor.
}
```

I was expecting to have ambiguity for the thirdCase, just like in the firstCase. But no! It calls the secondary constructor. Why?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of [method resolution](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html) in Kotlin (and in Java) can be a bit arcane. Thankfully, they do the obvious thing in nearly all situations — which is clearly the point! — but there are a few surprising corner cases.

The general principle is that it picks the *most specific* method that could match, and only gives an error if there isn't a single winner.

So in your second case, the arguments are `String` and `Int`. The candidates are the primary constructor (taking `String` and `Int?`), and the secondary constructor (taking `String` and `Int`). The latter is a more specific match, because `Int` is a subtype of `Int?`, and so it picks that one.

But in your first case, the only argument provided is a `String`, which matches both constructors equally, so there's no clear winner, and it flags up the ambiguity.

Your third case is even less obvious. However, the [section of the Kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#algorithm-of-msc-selection) that discusses how to choose the most specific candidate from all the overloads says:

> For each candidate we count the number of default parameters *not* specified in the call (i.e., the number of parameters for which we use the default value). The candidate with the least number of non-specified default parameters is a more specific candidate

I think that's what's happening in your third case: it picks the secondary constructor (which would leave only one parameter with its default value) over the primary (which would leave two).

Comment: You even added a link to the right documentation. Thanks! I feel smarter now!

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin gives more priority to a function that is more specific. Consider this example:

```kotlin
foo(dog) // invokes foo(Dog)

fun foo(animal: Animal) {}
fun foo(dog: Dog) {}
```

In this case `foo(dog)` is also ambiguous, but in fact, it uses `foo(Dog)` function. To use the other one, we have to explicitly upcast:

```kotlin
foo(dog as Animal)
```

Because `Int` is a subtype of `Int?`, your secondary constructor is more specific than the primary constructor and this is why it is preferred.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the third case.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, there is no ambiguity when you use two arguments, because it selects the constructor with the most specific type matching your parameter. There is no ambiguity to choose between the one with `Int` and the one with `Int?` because `Int` is more specific than `Int?`.

When you provide a single argument, it is ambiguous since you are not providing any argument that can help distinguish whether you want `Int` or `Int?`.